# Predictive Personalisation between different multi-tenancy sitecore websites

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, personalization, sitecore-analytics

We have different instances of websites some of them with up to 4 multisites each. They have their own XDB backend.

We have a requirement below:

> 1. Able to track the user between each sites. When user visits the dental site and comes to company main site then show the carousel
>      banner with dental Ads.
> 2. When user fills up the form or download certain PDF documents, increase the accumulated goals. e.g. if user visits dental site and
>      fills up form  (worth 10 points) and goes to different site and
>      downloads pdf (worth 5 points). The total goal value accumulated
>      should be 15.
> 3. Should be able to view the exact same user profile details (on each instances).

I understand we could use Federated experience manager, but above all are sitecore instances.

Would you able to help us how above can be achieved?
e.g.

> 1. Do we need to share same xDB and analytics Databases for ALL INSTANCES?
> 2. Does all sites need to be on SINGLE instance to achieve above?
> 3. Is it possible to share goals, personas, segments setup between different instances?
> 4. Any other recommendations?

Finally how does sitecore works out the predictive personalization i.e. it reads the xDB or analytics or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that there's no reason you can't use FXM on a Sitecore powered site. It does solve your problem, after all.

Comment: @StevieMcG, thanks. That is what I was thinking but not sure what are the limitation of FXM vs.  out of box. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do we need to share same xDB and analytics Databases for ALL
   INSTANCES? **Yes.**
2. Does all sites need to be on SINGLE instance to achieve
   above? **All sites can exist on separate instances, not an issue here.**
3. Is it possible to share goals, personas, segments setup
   between different instances? **Yes share the xDB among the instance, setup Database replication in CD and make sure machine key are same** *Please note that there lot of other things to be considered for coming to conclusion on this point.*

More reference links:

- http://digital-learnings.blogspot.in/2015/12/sitecore-multi-site-or-multi-instance.html
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/xdb_overview/scalability_options
- http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/whitepapers/Whitepaper-Planning-your-Sitecore-xDB-infrastructure.aspx

Comment: Thansk Harsh. Sitecore suggested that sharing xDB among multiple instance isn't supported.  Have you used this solution in prod with no issues?

Comment: @NilPun check the reference link to sitecore doc link given in the answer (this)[https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/xdb_overview/scalability_options] in that under heading `Sitecore xDB - fully scalable architecture (horizontal scaling)` it shows the diagram to share xDB i.e. Horizontal Scaling. I meant exactly this.

Comment: double confirmed that currently sitecore doesn't support sharing of SAME xDB database between multiple instance